# Keep 1 row of a group if any rows of the group meet a condition

Tags: r, tidyr

As part of a larger data-set, I have data along the lines of the following:

```
data <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
    Event = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    Date = c("12-24-2019", "12-25-2019",  "12-26-2019", "12-27-2019", "12-28-2019", "12-29-2019", "12-30-2019",  "12-31-2019", "12-01-2019", "12-02-2019", "12-03-2019", "12-04-2019"
 )
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Resulting in the following:

[image: data-table]

Essentially, I am wanting to end up with one row per ID, but which row is kept depends on whether the event occurred for an ID or not.

- If the event occurs for an ID, I want to keep the date that the event occurred and get rid of the other rows for that ID
- If the event does not occur at any point for an ID I want to keep the latest date and get rid of the other rows for that ID

Desired output:

[image: data table output]

I'm quite new to R and am not sure how to start with this - my googling hasn't helped!

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a`dplyr` solution using `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)


data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    Date = c(Date[Event == 1], last(Date))[1],
    Event = max(Event),
  )

# A tibble: 4 × 3
     ID Date       Event
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 12-24-2019     1
2     2 12-28-2019     0
3     3 12-31-2019     0
4     4 12-02-2019     1
```

This works for the provided data and for all datasets, where there is at most one event per `ID`. Otherwise the code would have to be slightly modified.

### Edit

If it is possible to have more Events per `ID` then we could use `tail` to get the Date of the last Event.

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    Date = c(tail(Date[Event == 1], 1), last(Date))[1],
    Event = max(Event),
  )
```

The idea is very simple: inside `summarise` I create a  `c(tail(Date[Event == 1], 1), last(Date))`

- The first element `tail(Date[Event == 1], 1)` is equal to the last entry (`tail(..., 1)`) of `Date` for which `Event == 1`. If no such entry exists this expression evaluates to a vector of length zero, making the overall vector length 1.
- The  second element is simply the last Date.

Finally, I  use `[1]` at the end to extract the first element of the vector described above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do unfortunately have a few IDs which have more than 1 event... how would I best modify this for that?

Comment: Thank you so much - that's worked perfectly! I don't suppose you'd mind explaining how it works so that I know for next time?

Comment: I added a small explanation

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but in my actual data-set there are many other columns and I am needing to keep the information in those as well. How could I modify this so that my out-put isn't only the ID, event and date, but that the entire row is kept?

Comment: I guess it's best to ask a new question for that case, as `summarise` would not be the best choice in that case